# copy with rsync when files are different

Tags: rsync

I have to copy a big directory to my NAS using rsync, I would like to say to rsync only copy the files when source and destination are different to avoid to copy a files already copied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skipping identical files is the whole purpose why people use rsync. This is default behavior of rsync. Most of the time the only option you want to use is `-a`:

```
rsync -a -P <source> <dest>
```

The `-P` just means show progress and the `-a` means "archive" and that means "when copying files, try to make copy as identical as possible" (try to keep permissions, ownership, timestamps, etc.) but is also means "Only update files if you have to". It's like saying "make sure `<dest>` is an up-to-date backup of `<source>`".

However, by default `rsync` will already consider two files identical, if they have same file size and same last modification date. Of course, two files may also have same size and same last modification date and not be identical. So when running that command for the very first time and you are not sure which files may need update and which ones don't, try this:

```
rsync -a -c -P <source> <dest>
```

`-c` means don't rely just upon size and date, checksum every file and compare the checksums. Only if checkums are identical, consider files as identical. Note that rsync will not necessary checksum the whole file, big files are broken into smaller chunks and every chunk is checksumed separately as only chunks that have changed are transferred.

So even with checksuming you can save you a lot of time when copying over a network connection. It won't save you any time when copying locally because just copying everything is probably faster than checksuming everything. So a plain copy will always beat a checksuming rsync in speed when both, source and destination, are local drives. In that case use

```
cp -a -v <source> <dest>
```

or if your system doesn't know `-a`, use

```
cp -pPR -v <source> <dest>
```

that's identical to `-a`. Again, the `-v` is just to see some progress.

And I'd only use `-c` for the very first sync, after that, relying on file size and last modification date usually works very well for updating and it is a whole lot faster. It will work because if a file has been altered since the last sync, it will have a different last modification date and so by just comparing the dates rysnc will know that the file must be updated at the destination. Of course, that only works if your systems all have the correct date/time set and if you don't manipulate the last modification date of files and also don't forbid your system to update them.

If you want to skip files solely on presence, use this:

```
rsync -a -P --ignore-existing <source> <dest>
```

That's like telling rsync "If you see a file with the same name at the destination, always consider it to be identical and never update it".

Please note that if `-a` detects a file in `<source>` is different than a files in `<dist>`, whether this is determined by size and modification date or by checksumming, it will always update the file at `<dest>` to match then file at `<source>`. If multiple sources are syncing to the same destination, you might also want to add `-u` which means "in case two files are different, only update if the file at `<source>` has a newer last modification date than then file at `<dest>`"

---

Just as a general tip, if you type

```
man <command>
```

in a terminal, you will get a nice help page on most systems (Linux, MacOS X and UNIX systems), explaining you all the options in all detail. You can scroll up/down using arrow keys or page up/down and you can leave that view by hitting "q" for quit. E.g.

```
man rsync
```

Comment: I started to copy my directory using cp... I want to continue without re-copy the files but rsync transfert the files already present

Comment: @Paul Then you didn't copy the files correctly. You should have copied them with `cp -a` or if your system doesn't know that flag, `cp -pPR` will do the same thing on most systems. It makes sure the files keep their modification date when copied; that way `rsync` will skip them just by the date test. To just skip files on presence, w/o checking size/date and w/o checksuming file content, use ` --ignore-existing`.

Comment: I already tried `--ignore-existing` but some files are incomplete and it skip them

Comment: @Paul You need to know what you want. If some files are incomplete, then you must checksum (`-c`) as shown in my answer above. rsync can skip files on presence, on checksum or on date/size - that's all it can do. If you need something else, then you need a different tool, then rsync won't help you.

Comment: According to `man` for rsync 3.1.3 proto v.31 `-a` does _not_ include any flags (such as `-u`, `-c` or `--ignore-existing`) to ignore already copied files. That would mean by default it is copying everything again.

Comment: @HomelessGamer The whole purpose of `rsync` is to only copy "changes" as pointed out by the description section of the man page, so copying as little as possible is something that `rsync` always does by default, you can only tell it how to achieve that goal (should it use file sizes and mod dates, should it used checksums, or should it use the sole existence of files). By default it uses sizes/dates and `-u` only tells it to ignore changes unless the mod date is newer (otherwise it would also copy if it is older but not if it is the same).

Comment: @HomelessGamer `-u` changes "only consider files with different size or mod date" to "only consider files with a **newer** mod date". Yet even when a file is considered, it is then still checksumed to verify there was really a change. `-c` changes that to always use checksum and ignore sizes/dates. And even if a file is considered as changed, it is not just copied as a whole, it is broken down into blocks (block size depends on file size), then each block is compared and only changed blocks are actually transferred.

Comment: @HomelessGamer You can very easily verify what I just told you. "mkdir /tmp/a /tmp/b; echo Test > /tmp/a/test.txt`. Now run `rsync -aP /tmp/a/ /tmp/b`. You see one file being copied. Run it again and you see no file is being copied. Change mod date of file using `touch /tmp/a/test.txt` then run rsync command again and file is copied again. See, as long as neither size nor mod date changes, rsync will not copy anything for existing files.

Comment: @Mecki Your are right. "Rsync  finds  files  that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or  in  last-modified  time."
Next time you edit your answer i can remove my downvote.